Using ng-bootstrap components is causing errors associated with my Content Security Policy
I have recently added a Content Security Policy and now I am getting the following error from using the ng-bootstrap Accordion and probably other similar components from this library:

Refused to load the image 'data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='none'
stroke='%23212529' stroke-linecap='round' stroke- .... ... because it
violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src
'self' 'nonce-5e3808cd

I believe this stems from ng-bootstrap's use of inline svg images such as this taken from an ng-bootstrap css class:
bs-accordion-btn-icon: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='none' stroke='%23212529' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'%3e%3cpath d='M2 5L8 11L14 5'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);

I am not sure how I can modify my Content Security Policy to correct this, without defeating the purpose for a CSP.  Is this something that can only be corrected in ng-bootstrap or can I address this in my application?  I would greatly appreciate help and an explanation of this issue.

Can't you avoid using an inline style?

Thanks for replying.  I have removed all inline styles from my application.  This issue is coming from ng-bootstrap.

if that is the case, create a new issue here. I just checked it, someone had apparently the same issue. https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues

A simple workaround to avoid opening up your CSP is to download the necessary SVG, host within assets for the project and override the css binding for bs-accordion-btn-icon. Admittedly this is not ideal.
